# Does every convex, nonempty, body have a supporting line at every point?

Tags: geometry, geodesic

> Does every convex, nonempty, body have a supporting line at every point on its boundary?

This seems intuitively true to me, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to prove it. I was thinking of using a slicing argument. That is, cut a line through the body and then we have a set of curves which are convex. So more generally, do we need to prove that every convex function has a supporting line at every point?

Comment: You may be missing the word *boundary* in your question.  Points in the interior clearly do not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [supporting hyperplane theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane) says a convex set in $\mathbb R^n$ has a supporting hyperplane at every point of its boundary.  Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Hi, I need help proving this: If a convex, closed, nonempty figure $K$ lies inside a given circle $\omega$, then given any point $P$ on its circumference, a supporting line can be drawn from that point to $K$.

Comment: Let $R(\theta)$ be the ray from $P$ at angle $\theta$.  Take a maximal interval $[a,b]$ such that $R(\theta)$ intersects $K$ for $a \le \theta \le b$.  then $R(a)$ and $R(b)$ will be supporting lines.

Comment: That's not a proof.

Comment: It's not a detailed proof.  Each statement needs to be proven, but is not difficult.  The details are left up to you.

Comment: The details aren't clear to me. Can you post your answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744073/supporting-lines-to-convex-figure-in-a-circle